# how can I stop one app using other app

Tags: iphone

I need to create a app which is responsible for closing the other 
apps which are currently running in background , is it possible ? 
if it is possible then how ? plz help

Comment: When your app runs, it is the only app in foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No definitely not. When you launch or run an app in the iPhone, it is the only app that is running in the foreground as of now. I am not sure Apple have introduced something like running numerous apps on the Foreground. Maybe it may be possible in the future.. Maybe an iPhone10 or something. but this is not possible now. When you run the app all other applications are taken to the background and you won't be able to access them.. sorry...

Answer (score 4):

Hmm. On iPhones, there is only one app which is running in the foreground. By starting your app, all other apps are forced into the background - problem solved :)

In case you meant terminating other apps that are running in the *background*, then no, that is not possible, and there is a pretty good reason for that.

Answer (score 2):

No, thats not possible. You have no access from your app to other apps.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone doesnt allow other apps to close apps running in background. Nor does it allow deleting them.

**Its considered a security risk.**